# How to `rm *`, an actual file named "*"?

Tags: command-line, bash

I don't know how this happened, but I have a broken symlink in my home directory named `*`. I was just about to `rm *`, and then I had a facepalm moment. Should I `rm \*`? `rm '*'`? Something else? Backing up now...

Comment: @slhck A broken symlink is not a directory. You do not generally remove directories and files the same way. Here the '*' file is not under the file system root. There are more than one question in Dan Ross' one. Bottom line: I would not close that question.

Comment: @jlliagre The questions are not the same, but the answers are, and they boil down to escaping the glob, or quoting it, so anybody looking to remove such a file should find the answers helpful.

Comment: @slhck I agree there are many similarities and the other answers would have been helpful but they do not suggest using `-i` which I guess is the reason why I quickly got upvotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both `rm \*` and `rm '*'` would be fine, `rm "*"` too.

When in doubt, you should use the `-i` option for `rm` to prompt you before removing a file. For example this command will remove all files which name has only one character but only if you accept it:

```
rm -i ?
```

Comment: Thank you, this is not the sort of thing I like to experiment with. If I screwed up and had to restore from a backup, then the timestamps on all my files would be reset. Not the end of the world, but certainly not cool. Accepting in 49 seconds...